# Not able to access the router

Tags: connection

Let me tell how the connection is

```
                                Computer 1 (192.168.1.2 , (not static)
                                |           
Internet --- Modem --- Switch --
                                |
                                 Wireless Router ( D- Link) - > Computer 2 (192.168.0.103)
```

This is my setup. I dont have any problem in accessing the internet connection but the problem is accessing the router from computer 1. Im able to access modem from computer 1 but not the router

At the same time im able to access router and modem from computer 2.

Answer (score 0):

Your computers on on two different subnets. The easy solution is to change computer 1 to `192.168.0.2`